# AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool not smooth with AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, iphone, core-animation, avfoundation, quartz-core

I'm exporting with `AVAssetExportSession` an `AVMutableVideoComposition` containing an `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` loaded with `CAKeyframeAnimation`.

Unfortunately the rendering of the animations in the outputted movie are not fluid at all, especially in 1920 x 1080.
Everything works fine in an `AVPlayerItem` but it's only when exporting that it become laggy and jumpy.
Anyone knows how to make the animations run smoothly in the exported movie?

I tried to use [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession) and changed the movie frame rate to 25 but it didn't help.

My `CAKeyframeAnimation` uses `keyTimes` and `timingFunctions` with timing being:

```
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]
```

Comment: If you play the rendered movie frame by frame does the animation appear as you would expect or is it "jumpy"?

Comment: well actually the issue was linked to the player rather than the encoder. indeed you have the right question. the movie plays smoothly on a tv screen but become jumpy in quicktime